# Why is it wrong for google to show its own other products in its search results?

Tags: india, antitrust-law

Google is facing antitrust probe in India. I don't know about other countries but what Indian law is broken in google search? Google search is a private free product. Why is it bad to prefer its own other products like google-maps instead of bing-maps?

http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/tech/internet/antitrust-probe-into-google-moves-into-next-phase/articleshow/48751439.cms

Answer (score 3):

Its just free enterprise, right?

Well ... except when there is a law that says its not allowed. I am unfamiliar with Indian law but the relevant law in Australia is the Trade Practices Act which deals with this under the category of [Misuse of Market Power](http://www.accc.gov.au/business/anti-competitive-behaviour/misuse-of-market-power). In a nutshell:

> A business with a substantial degree of power in a market is not allowed to use this power for the purpose of eliminating or substantially damaging a competitor or to prevent a business from entering into a market.

By preferring their products over a competitor's in their search engine they are "... eliminating or substantially damaging a competitor ...".

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add comments yet (darn low reputation), so I'm saying this here:

This same issue is very big in the EU. Google us under scrutiny for not providing equal advertisement/favoring their own products. According to *many* New York Times articles, this is the EU trying to promote their own businesses and decrease reliance on US companies; it is definitely not just righteousness. I am not sure if this is the same or even similar scenario in India.

At least in the U.S., this issue is known as *net-neutrality*.